# how to pass value from for loop variable on button click function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I don't know if it is possible or not or it might be a silly question. But here is what I need to do:

```
  @{
      var data= "";
    }
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
         @if (Context.User.Identity.Name == "admin")
         {
           <td style="width:50px;">
             @if (@item.chkbillboard == true)
                 {<input name ="chk1" class="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" value="@item.chkbillboard" checked="checked" />   
                 data = data + item.id + "," + item.appname + ";";
                 }
                 else
                 {<input name ="chk2" class="myCheckbox" id="chkbox" type="checkbox" value="@item.chkbillboard" onclick="return chkbox();" />
                 }
            </td>     
         }
         <td style="width:200px;">@item.appname </td> 
         <td style="width:50px;">@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UpdateAPIForm", new { @id = item.id, appname = item.appname })</td>
    </tr>
}


    @if (Context.User.Identity.Name == "admin")
    {
       <div class="grid_1 sub-spacer editor-field submit">&nbsp;</div>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" id ="demo-submit1"  onclick="return chkchkbox(data);"  /> <br />
    }
```

In my for loop I assiged some value if the check box is true. What I need to do is I want to pass this data variable with values on button click to my javascript function.

Like `onclick="return chkchkbox(data);"`

I don't know if it is possible. If not, is there any other way to pass value on button click?

Comment: Please fix your code indentation.

Comment: you mean you want the value associated to the checkbox?

Comment: Soory I fixed my code indention

Comment: Yes the value I assigned in checkbox if checkbox is checked in variable "data".I want to pass this on my button clcik event

Comment: As an aside, you should really use CSS for your styling, not embedded styles like you have. Inline styles on tables really set you up for failure in cross-browser scenarios. Don't mean to be a douche, sorry if it comes across that way...

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem resolved .
I used onclick="return chkchkbox('@data');" 
on button click event and it worked for me.